# How does .sid files handled in Ubuntu?

Tags: sound

I had .sid files in a folder. Sid files are special sound files.

When I used Windows, the .sid files required to download a software to play them.
Since some time I switched to Ubuntu, and by looking in the the folder, I was interested that the icon was a music file and by opening it **I was amazed that it opened successfully**. It was incredible for me since on Windows it was harsh to make them playing.

But then comes my question: **How the H€(|< can Ubuntu plays .sid files?!?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.sid` files are handled through "MIME", a multimedia extension to, of all things, E-mail.

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ mimetype *.sid
*.sid: audio/prs.sid
walt@bat:~(0)$
```

Read `man update-mime` and `man mailcap`. You may even wish to `less /etc/mailcap`, but meanwhile:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ grep audio/prs.sid /etc/mailcap
audio/prs.sid; audacious %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"
audio/prs.sid; totem --fullscreen %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"
walt@bat:~(0)$
```

This shows that there are two choices for playing files with mimetype `audio/prs.sid` (and here's the command), filename `*.sid`.

Comment: And Windows doesn't use MIME?
I guess.

Comment: AskUbuntu is a Q&A site, not a conversation site, AND we don't know about Windows (annd don't want to).